# AMBA AHB protocol wrap address using SV randomazation

Tags: system-verilog

How to write the wrap calculation  coding using System Verilog          and the parameters are hsize[2:0] hburst[2:0]  & haddr[31:0] in random constraint

```
class adddress_cal;
rand bit[31:0]haddr;
rand bit[2:0]hsize;
rand bit[2:0]hburst;
//how to write the random constraint for wrap address
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constraint addr_in_4k { haddr%4096 + (hburst + 1 << hsize) <= 4096;}
```

Comment: why 4096 ahb support only 1k and plz explain (hburst + 1 << hsize) why hburst +1

Comment: That's probably another question. This was just a representative way of writing the constraint.

Comment: suppose my hzise is 2 and hburst is 2 statring haddr is 32'h0X38 then how to write